# How do you solve this quadratic matrix equation?

Tags: matrix-analysis, quadratic-forms, matrix-equations

could you please help me solve this quadratic matrix equation? I look around, seems like there is no general solution for it..
$$-BX^2 + X - C = 0$$ for X, B and C are (3x3) matrices. B and C are matrices of constant, solve for X.
$$(-B_{3x3}X^2_{3x3} + X_{3x3} - C_{3x3} = 0)$$

Answer (score 3):

[This question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/245667/) is not an exact duplicate, but my answer gives you a pointer that applies also to your case.